# Change specific column if equal to something AWK

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a list of search phrases.  I'm trying to replace the third column to N/A if it is equal to "error".  I used the following code to sucessfully do this on the second column.  So, I'm not sure why it isn't working on the third column.  Any thoughts?

```
data
protector new ipad,0,error
60 led lcd television,0,error
boost mobile new phone 2013,0,error
seagate st320014a,0,error

awk -F, '{$3=($3=="error"?"N/A":$3)}1' OFS=, nTotal.csv > n3Total.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `awk` command is correct, not efficient but correct. However, there could be other reasons as to why it may not be working.

- There could be a trailing space after the `error`. Since you testing an exact match of the third column, it could fail.
- You files are dos formatted. If you made the files on windows machine and are using it on unix/linux machines then you need to convert those line endings. Doing `cat -vet` will show `^M` characters at the end. You can use `dos2unix` or similar utilities to convert it to unix format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `awk`

```
awk -F, '$3=="error" {$3="N/A"}1' OFS=, file
data
protector new ipad,0,N/A
60 led lcd television,0,N/A
boost mobile new phone 2013,0,N/A
seagate st320014a,0,N/A
```

---

Your solution gives:

```
data,,
protector new ipad,0,N/A
60 led lcd television,0,N/A
boost mobile new phone 2013,0,N/A
seagate st320014a,0,N/A
```

You see the extra `,,` after data, since it creates two extra field in the way you are testing.